# Pygame loop not running

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a qr code generator as a small project. Currently it should only print 2 lines on the top of the screen. but the second for loop doesnt run at all. i changed the variables and such. I dont understand why the for loop doesnt activate at all.

```py
import pygame,random,os
pygame.init()
rand=random.Random()
#use https://www.qr-code-generator.com/

#Setup
WIDTH,HEIGHT=210,210
WIN=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("QR code generator")
WIN.fill((255,255,255))
x=0
y=0
dothisthing=True
d=0
f=0
def doit(xm,ym):
  
  pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (0,0,0), pygame.Rect(xm,ym,10,10))


for l in range(6):
  doit(d,f)
  pygame.display.update()
  d+=10
d=14
f=0
for y in range(6):
  doit(d,f)
  pygame.display.update()
  d+=10



run=True
while run:


  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run=False  
  
  
  
  


  pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using 14 instead of 140. This caused the boxes to overlap. The only help I got was to limit cpu usage and update game states, so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).